# Adding in a $ with decimal points using PHP

Tags: php, decimal

I need to add in a number with 2 decimal points with $/USD. I am not very sure how to go about adding in the $ or USD to my codes.

!EDITS AND PURPOSE: 
Here is what I need to achieve:

1. As long as the number is a decimal with more than 2 numbers and does not have a (-), I have to show it in 2 decimal places.
2. If it is an integer, I have to show it in 2 decimal places but it cannot be a single digit number as that will not be used for currency but as a COUNT of something. I have to make sure it is not a date and does not have the (-) separator.
3. If it is a string, it will just display the value and do nothing.

   ```
   $float = floatval($val);//checking for decimal if it is present

   if($float && intval($float) != $float && strlen($float) > 3 && strpos($val,'-') == false){ 
       echo number_format($float,2); //placing it in 2 decimal points
   }
   elseif ($float && intval($float) == $float && strlen($float) > 3 && strpos($val,'-') == false){
       echo number_format($float,2); 
   }
   else{
       echo $val; //if does not fit the criteria then place just show the value
   }
   ```

Comment: the same way you add any string\variable?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: do you want to display the value in decimal format? is that what u meant?

Comment: I don't really see what you are trying to do here. You check: If `$float` evaluates to true + You check if `$float` has decimal places + You check if `$float` is longer than 3 characters + And you check if the return value of `strpos($val,'-')` is false, with a loosely comparison, which means it also could be at the start.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do; Please make a simple example with what you have as input and what you try to archive as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [number_format](http://php.net/number_format)

```
return number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

For example -

```
$number = "200";
echo number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');  
// Result -> 200.00
```

To add "$"-

```
$yourval=200.00
echo "$".$yourval; // results $200.00
```

Comment: It is already in decimal. I need to add a $ inside.

Comment: The .$yourval is from?

Comment: `$yourval` i just mentioned a variable that contains value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a PHP function (like money_format()) to convert to a currency-type format, you'll have to make your own.  If you want to indicate dollars, prepend the literal string "$" to the floating point value.  Here are some examples:

```
<?php

echo "$" . $whatever;

$moneyvalue = "$" . $floatvalue;
echo $moneyvalue;

function FormatMoney($x) {
    return "$" . $x;
}
echo FormatMoney($myfloatvalue);

?>
```

Comment: How do I prepend it inside?

Comment: I will just leave a link here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php see Example #1. Won't work on Windows though and there could be limitations, so... your answer isn't quite correct.